# Create a Resource Controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to make a resource controller in my package but i'm not sure how to do it.

Normally I would use:

```
php artisan controller:make MyController
```

But how can I make it so this is created in my package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at  `php artisan help controller:make` you will see that there is a path option, so I guess that's what you're looking for.

Another option would be to explore the [workbench](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/74) which will make things easier while developing a package

Comment: Thanks, it's php artisan controller:make MyController --bench acme-inc/my-package